# How can I get KeyListener to properly work with JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, keylistener, jogl

I'm trying to use a KeyListener to change a value specifically *rtri*, and therefore change how my animation works. My code is kinda all over so sorry in advance!

I've tried making an instance of KeyListener inside of setup() and using .addKeyListener() to add it to the canvas.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class Frame implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {

    public final double pi2 = (2 * Math.PI);
    private GLU glu = new GLU();
    private float rtri = 0.0f;
    private static ArrayList<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
    private static float zFloat = 1.0f;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            rtri += 0.5f;
            System.out.println(rtri);
            System.out.println("Increase");
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            rtri -= 0.5f;
            System.out.println(rtri);
            System.out.println("Decrease");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
            final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClear( GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View
        gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f ); // Move the plane of stars

        gl.glRotatef( rtri, 0.0f, -2.0f, zFloat ); // Rotate the plane

        for (int sNum = 0; sNum < stars.size(); sNum++) {
            drawStar(stars.get(sNum), gl);
            }

        gl.glFlush();
            rtri+= 5.0f;

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, 
        int height) {
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 
           // get the OpenGL 2 graphics object  
        if(height <=0)
        height =1;
           //preventing divided by 0 exception height =1;
        final float h = (float) width / (float) height;
           // display area to cover the entire window
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
           //Transforms projection matrix
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluPerspective( 45.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0 );
           //transforming model view gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void setup() {
        final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);


        final GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
        Frame bFrame = new Frame();

        canvas.addGLEventListener(bFrame);
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
        canvas.setSize(900, 900);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Window");

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60,true);
        animator.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().setup();

    }

}
```

In my keyPressed, I have it set so that if I were to press the up arrow, it would increase rtri, print out its value, and print the word "Increase." When I run the program, the animation works fine, but pressing on either of the keys has no effect on my program nor do they print the desired items in the console.

Comment: Add the key listener into the frame.